# How to mock a multivalued map that sent along with post request using jersey client?

Tags: java, web-services, jersey, jersey-client

```
MultivaluedMap<String, String> formData = new MultivaluedMapImpl();
        formData.add(FRIENDLY_NAME, tenDlcRegistration.getSiteName());
        formData.add(EMAIL, notificationEmail);
        formData.add(POLICY_SID, policySid);
```

how to mock the above one to send as form data with post request?